# AngularJS and JQuery not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a page that uses jquery and is working perfectly. The JQuery is located inside two files: control.js and lightgallery.js. The minute I add in AngularJS all of my jquery stops working. I need to find a way to have my jquery work without learning how to rewrite all of the functions in angular. Any suggestions?

None of the html I've added with the ngInclude is using angular. It's just simple html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>H</title>
<!-- STYLESHEETS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/common/css/split.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/common/css/control.css">
    <!-- JQUERY -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/common/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="/assets/common/js/control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- ANGULAR -->
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="home">


<div ng-include="'../assets/includes/left-panel.html'"></div>

<!-- / START TEMPLATE -->
<div ng-include="'../assets/includes/template.html'"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what part of jQuery doesn't work (preferably with code)? Also, it looks like you've done more than just "add" Angular: you've at least moved some HTML into partials loaded by `ngInclude`, so expanding on what precisely you did may be helpful.

Comment: None of the html I've added with the ngInclude is using angular. It's just html.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what is happening:

Your jQuery code probably runs on document ready:

```
$(function(){
     //your initialization code here
});
```

The problem is that the elements in your templates that your jQuery plugins are targeting are not yet added to the DOM when this function runs.  This is because Angular has not yet inserted these templates into the DOM.

You can verify this by removing the ng-includes and replacing them with the markup contained in the templates themselves (bypassing ng-include).

This is a classic "mistake" when using Angular along with jQuery plugins.

The only "correct" way to integrate jQuery plugins with Angular is to wrap the plugins in a directive.

Comment: Can you tell me how to wrap the plugins in a directive? Is that easy to do? It sounds like just putting a piece of angular code before and after the jquery plugin.

Comment: I posted the 2 jquery plugin files I am using. I don't think the lightgallery plugin is running on document ready. I could be wrong.

Comment: I would recommend reading the [documentation for directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  [This article may also be helpful](http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html)

Comment: Ok, I will read all of the documentation and article. But can you tell me what I am trying to do is easy? Because if it's going to take me hours and hours to figure this out, I might want to just get someone that knows what they are doing to help me. btw - thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I'm afraid that migrating a jQuery application over to Angular isn't necessarily easy.  The second article I mentioned might clear up your questions.   Beyond explaining "why" what you are doing isn't working, I'm not sure I can do much to help you much further.